# O que acontece se o verbo não estiver no ínicio da frase, mas sim, conjugado no futuro?

Tags: colocação-pronominal

O site soportugues.com.br escreve [aqui](http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/sint/sint74.php) que

> Se o verbo não estiver no início da frase, nem conjugado nos tempos Futuro do Presente ou Futuro do Pretérito, é possível usar tanto a próclise como a ênclise.

Mas o que acontece se o verbo *não estiver no ínicio da frase*, mas *sim, conjugado no futuro*?

Qual a frase correta aqui:

> Eles convidar-me-ão para a festa.

ou

> Eles me convidarão para a festa.

Comment: Lê a frase da citação assim: `Se o verbo não estiver NEM no início da frase, nem conjugado (...) no futuro, [etc]`. A tua dúvida mantém-se?

Comment: @ANeves, eu acho que sim. Daí será "Eles convidar-me-ão para a festa." Certo?

Comment: No português brasileiro, pode considerar que nunca se usa a mesóclise na fala, e mesmo na escrita culta ela costuma ser evitada quando possível.

Comment: Em Português de Portugal consideraria certa apenas a primeira opção

Comment: Em pt-BR "Eles convidar-me-ão para a festa" (errado), pois usa-se a mesóclise quando não há pronome antes do verbo "Convidar-nos-ão para a festa".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Brasil, a primeira construção, com a mesóclise, é inaceitável no coloquial, e aceitável, porém não preferível, no padrão. Diríamos antes "*Eles vão me convidar para a festa*". (Ou, mais escorreitamente, "*Eles vão-me convidar para a festa*", que é horroroso, mas é como manda a Dona Gramática Normativa, empunhando, ameaçadora, a palmatória.)

A segunda construção é inaceitável no padrão, e eu diria que muito duvidosa no coloquial. Parece alguém tentando usar o padrão onde o que cabe é o uso do coloquial - e fazendo-o de forma equivocada, ainda por cima, o que aponta para algo semelhante a esse bicho-papão da língua, a hipercorreção... De novo, creio que o uso preferido/preferível é com o futuro composto, com o verbo "ir" de auxiliar: "*Eles vão me convidar para a festa*" (E mandamos Dona Gramática Normativa e seu maldito hífen às favas; aqui no coloquial, como em Grândola, quem manda é o povo!).

(O @bfavaretto disse basicamente a mesma coisa em menos palavras no comentário acima.)

Comment: Eu uso muitas vêzes a mesóclise do primeiro exemplo em pt-BR quando quero dar ênfase ou tem tom de brincadeira com meus familiares e amigos.  Com estranhos certamente soaria pedante.  Conheço também muita gente bem letrada que faz o mesmo, usar um vocabulário ou construções bizarras para fazer piada.

Comment: @Centaurus Dizeis a verdade; sói ocorrer amiúde. Mas aí acho que sai um pouco do registro coloquial e vai para o poético/literário (e tem de terminar na primeira gargalhada, caso contrário pode virar fiasco).

Comment: Em "Eles me convidarão para a festa", o pronome "Eles" não puxa o "me" para perto dele? Quanto a "Eles vão-me convidar para a festa", não entendi, você queria escrever "Eles vão convidar-me para a festa"?

Comment: @AndréLyra - não, definitivamente o "eles" não "puxa" o pronome clítico. Ao que ao saiba, as únicas palavras em posição de sujeito que atraem o clítico são pronomes indefinidos, do tipo "alguém", "ninguém", "algo", etc. (Mas esse raciocínio é mais válido para o português europeu, onde de fato a ênclise é a norma, mesmo no coloquial. No Brasil, a norma parece ser a próclise.)

Comment: @AndréLyra E, claro, "Eles vão-me convidar para a festa" é uma construção tão esquisita que você acha que me enganei. Mas é a norma culta; por algum motivo misterioso a gramática manda colocar hífen entre o auxiliar e o clítico.

Comment: Em pt-BR "Eles me levarão" é correto, errado seria "Eles levarão-me", é mais correto mas sem nenhum uso "Eles levar-me-ão" . "Os pronomes indefinidos e relativos e as conjunções subordinativas, palavras de valor negativo, Advérbios de um modo geral atraem o pronome". Eu pensei no pronome 'eles' puxando o obliquo pois é o uso comum no Brasil, mas aceita-se "Ele se manteve / manteve-se", tanto faz.